# Netezza - How to return multiple values from a stored procedure without REFTABLE

Tags: stored-procedures, netezza, nzplsql

I try to return a few values from a stored procedure without using reftable in Netezza.

`CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TMP_GETTABLEINFO(CHAR(any), VARCHAR(any), VARCHAR(any)) 
returns char(1), varchar(30)
EXECUTE AS OWNER
LANGUAGE NZPLSQL
AS
begin_proc
DECLARE
    a ALIAS FOR $1;
    b ALIAS FOR $2;
BEGIN
...
RETURN a, b;
END;`

Is it possible?
How?

My results are: `ERROR [HY000] ERROR:  Must specify LANGUAGE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible. I haven't seen a case with multiple values being returned.

From the documentation (Netezza_stored_procedures_guide.pdf): Typically, an NZPLSQL procedure returns a unique return value, but it can also return a result set in the form of a specified table.

To create a stored procedure that returns a result set:

- Define the stored procedure with a return value of `RETURNS REFTABLE (<table-name>)` to indicate that it returns a result set that looks like the specified table.
- Inside the body of the procedure, use the variable `REFTABLENAME` to refer to the results table.